# coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found in python

Tags: python, networking, tcp, websocket

I am busy with TCP Socket programing to handle gttp requests, when i try connect from another host i get this error amongst some junk. This is the error i got

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3140009_2.py", line 43, in <module>
    main()
  File "3140009_2.py", line 21, in main
    f = open(filename[1:])
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found
```

the code that is giving this erros is

```
while True:
    print ('Ready to serve...')
    connectionSocket, add = serverSocket.accept()
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        print (message, "::", message.split()[0], ':', message.split()[1])
        filename = (message.split()[1], ':')
        print (filename, '||', filename[1:])
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata = f.read()
        print (outputdata)
```

Comment: Did you try passing something other than a tuple?

Comment: You are actually trying to open file `(':',)`. That's a tuple, not a filename.